# Subprocess Popen Communicate Crashing Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, stdout, stdin

Here I have a thread that uses stdout to read live output from a batch file, and it works great.

```
file_path = *directory of batch file*
p = sub.Popen('run.bat', cwd=file_path, stdout=sub.PIPE, stdin=sub.PIPE)

def insert():
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if p.poll() is not None:
            break
        if line:
            output = line.strip().decode('utf-8')
            listbox.insert(END, output)

insert_thread = threading.Thread(target=insert)
insert_thread.daemon = True
insert_thread.start()
```

My problem comes when I try to write input to the batch file, it passes the input but then immediately crashes my Tkinter window.

```
def send_input(command):
    p.stdin.write(command.encode())
    output = p.communicate()[0]


send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send, args=(cmd.get(),))
```

*then I called the thread in a Tkinter button command.*

I want to be able to write input to the batch file and read its output at the same time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you closing stdin (`p.stdin.close()`) just after you write to it? Also you might want to run `p.communicate()` in another thread

Comment: I removed the stdin.close() and ran p.communicate() in another thread. it didn't crash now but the input didn't reach the batch file, and also when I wanted to send another input it gave me a RuntimeError saying that threads can only be started once.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the new code? It think something might be wrong with your thread (maybe?)

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure what could be wrong, maybe you see something?

Comment: From your code I can't see most of the things I need to see to figure out the problem. Can you please most a minimal working example that I can copy/paste and try it myself? Btw I am also creating my own terminal [here](https://github.com/TheLizzard/CPP-IDLE/tree/main/src/terminal.pyw). It works but isn't the best. You might want to look at it/copy parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working when I used `stdin.write()` only, without `communicate()`. I tried it before and the batch file didn't seem to get the input, but I realized now that I forgot to put `stdin.flush()` and now it all works perfectly. Thanks for the help.